# How to deny java preferences import into node xy

Tags: java, permissions, import, preferences

I am using:

```
java.util.prefs.Preferences.importPreferences( new FileInputStream(xmlFile) );
```

to allow the user to restore some exported data.

Every xml should look like: (the generated format via `Preferences.importPreferences()`)

```
    <?xml ...
    <!DOCTYPE ...
    <preferences ...
      <root type="user">
        <map/>
        <node name="com">
          <map/>
          <node name="data">
            <map/>
            <node name="core">
              <map/>
              <node name="default">
                <map/>
                <entry key...
              </node>
            </node>
          </node>
        </node>
      </root>
    </preferences>
```

I want deny any import in other nodes than (eg. ... `/JavaSoft/Prefs/com/data/core/default/`)

How can I prevent importing manipulated xml, without parsing the whole file?

Answer (score 1):

The only way you could do this, is to create an md5 hash for each and every file that is exported so you can use it to verify that it is still valid. These md5 files should be kept in a location seperate to the original files to prevent people from also manipulating those.